# Docker ADD does not copy the contents of a subfolder

Tags: docker, dockerfile

While building my dev environment (Linux Mint 18.3) I had to create a docker file which has the instructions:

```
FROM centos:7

ENV CATALINA_HOME /opt/tomcat
ADD apache-tomcat-8.5.5 ${CATALINA_HOME}
```

where the apache-tomcat-8.5.5 is a folder with all the files to deploy tomcat-8.5.5 that can be obtained from:

```
https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.5/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.5.tar.gz
```

ADD copies all the files excepting the content at ~/apache-tomcat-8.5.5/webapps/. Does anyone had a similar problem? I even changed the permissions to be RW by anyone yet  the problem persist.

I am running this docker using

```
docker run -v /opt/webapi/tomcat/webapps:/opt/tomcat/webapps -v /opt/webapi/tomcat/logs:/opt/tomcat/logs  .....
```

Could this sharing be deleting the contents in webapps? If this is the case how can we do to avoid this? I do not have any dockerignore file

Comment: How do you run your container or inspect the image? Is there a volume defined? Do you have a `.dockerignore` file?

Comment: I just use the docker run cmd sharing the webapps folder. Could this sharing be deleting the files inside this folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am running this docker using
>
> ```
> docker run -v /opt/webapi/tomcat/webapps:/opt/tomcat/webapps -v /opt/webapi/tomcat/logs:/opt/tomcat/logs  .....
> ```

You overwrite the `webapps` directory with the host mount to `/opt/webapi/tomcat/webapps`. Only files in that directory on the host will be visible inside that container. The files are most likely being copied into the image, but with that volume mount the files inside the image cannot be seen.

If you do not want to replace the directory inside the container with this host directory, then do not create a volume mount. If you want to overwrite the host directory with the contents from the image, you can do this in an entrypoint, or switched to a named volume. A named volume is initialized when it is empty, and you can point back to any folder on the host be passing options to the volume driver. Here are several examples of a named bind mount:

```
  # create the volume in advance
  $ docker volume create --driver local \
      --opt type=none \
      --opt device=/home/user/test \
      --opt o=bind \
      test_vol

  # create on the fly with --mount
  $ docker run -it --rm \
    --mount type=volume,dst=/container/path,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=none,volume-opt=o=bind,volume-opt=device=/home/user/test \
    foo

  # inside a docker-compose file
  ...
  volumes:
    bind-test:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: none
        o: bind
        device: /home/user/test
  ...
```

For copying the files inside an entrypoint, see the `save-volume` and `load-volume` scripts in my [docker-base](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base) repo. This would give you the flexibility to always overwrite the contents on the host with the saved values in the image. Though if you do this, consider whether you really needed a volume, and how you plan to avoid data loss by overwriting user changes.